# How to avoid further processing after redirect in a JSF action method?

Tags: session, jsf, redirect

Having a simple .xhtml, mainly with a button going outside:

```
<html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
  <f:view>
    <h:body>
      <h:form>
        <h:messages id="messages" />
        <h:outputLabel for="name-field" /><h:inputText id="name-field" value="#{mySession.name}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myService.goOutside}" />
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

And a simple backing bean supporting it:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MySession implements Serializable {
  private String name = "My Name";

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MySession.class.getName());

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    LOG.info("MySession initialized!");
  }
}
```

And the `RequestScoped` bean supporting the `goOutside` service method:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyService {
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class.getName());

  public String goOutside() throws IOException {
    LOG.info("Enter goOutside");
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession(); // To make sure that old session with old user defaults are not retained!
    ec.redirect("https://en.wikipedia.org/");
    LOG.info("Exit goOutside");
    return null;
  }
}
```

This works as expected - after "Exit goOutside" is logged, I do not see "MySession initialized!" until and unless I revisit my original xhtml.

In the context of my complete code - which down to those portions looks essentially the same, I do not get that behaviour: the `MySession` bean gets reinitialized right after the redirect, and before I revisit the original URL.

I am still trying to strip down the original code until it works finding out the point at which it should break with minimal amount of code - but I feel it might take me a while due to the way it is woven into the rest.

If any idea in what this issue would be introduced - this would shorten my research. Or I could rephrase my question as: "What do I add into above code so that I see MySession initialized right away?".

Comment: Hi, JSF does not know you are on an external site, so 3 things you should do 1: [mcve], 2: [mcve] and 3: [mcve], and one more 4: post version info.

Comment: Yeah - I was working it into a more complete example. But the simplified example shows the correct behavior: after the `invalidateSession` and the `redirect` is executed, the bean is not accessed anymore, until I go back to the original URL causing the session bean to be reinitialized (not reused). Somehow in my more complex code, there is still something that causes the bean to be reinitialized right after the button action is being executed. Trying to find out what is different by stripping the code - but that will take me a good amount of time. This question is not valid anymore.

Comment: some javascript unload event that does a request to something that creates a session might do this

Comment: You will be right. In fact I can see an `OmniFaces.Unload.init`, but even if I trigger that to be included by including some component using omnifaces, I am still not able to replicate. Even trying to debug javascript to trap it. I am not sure if it will be worth the effort finding out what is causing an unload triggering the reinstantiation. Maybe I should simply focus on finding a solution that avoids any unload events to happen.